# New Motherboard, but no display output on motherboard nor on graphic card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

I got a new Asus P8H77 -V LE and installed it into my PC:

- Asus P8H77 -V LE
- Intel i5-3550
- Saphire Radeon HD 7870 GHz Edition
- 8GB-Kit G.Skill PC3-10667U CL9
- WD Caviar Green 1TB
- Thermaltake Hamburg (Power Supply) 530W

At first, I forgot to connect my graphic card and re-installed Windows and the motherboard drivers. When I tried to install my video card driver, I realized that the video card wasn't being recognized and saw that I had forgotten to connect the card to the power supply.

Now I don't get any display output on either the onboard socket from my motherboard or from the graphic card, however Windows boots (I can hear the login sound from Windows). Could it be that my graphic card is broken? Any other ideas are welcome since I'd rather not have to buy a new one.

Comment: Make sure you disable iGPU/dGPU support in your motherboard settings, and that the default graphics adapter is set to an external PCIe one.  Do you have another graphics card lying around you could test the system with?  If you *remove* the graphics card entirely, does the computer still work fine with the with the onboard graphics?

Comment: You don't get ANY display output, does that mean you also don't see any BIOS messages?

Comment: Sadly i don't have another graphics card lying around. To answer your questions: @Breakthrough when i remove my graphics card and use the iGPU it works totally fine.

Comment: @Jakke yes, i mean that i don't get any output at all; no BIOS messages nor anything else, but as i said i can hear my pc boot. as in that i hear the windows login sounds.

Comment: sounds more like a cabling or monitor hardware issue to me then

Comment: @Jakke It is said that without the graphic card it works totally fine, so it's not a cabling or monitor hardware issue.

Comment: BIOS messages are always displayed over the internal or discreet GPU, no matter what the BIOS settings are. If they are not displayed at all, it means the monitor doesn't receive the signal. Windows boots normally (listening from the sounds), so no internal hardware problems are detected. To me, that can only mean that the monitor doesn't receive the signal over the cable it's connected with, or the monitor fails.

Answer (score 1):

Try to completely disconnect your graphics card.
Then check if you get a video signal from your motherboard. If you still get a black screen then it's your motherboard or your CPU that's the problem.
If you do get a signal from the motherboard then it's you graphics card or the PCI slot the graphics card is plugged in to. Try moving your graphics card to another PCI slot. If this doesn't work then your graphics card is broken.
Hopefully this helped :D

Comment: So as i commented above, my computer works fine without the graphics card. from what's written on my motherboard the PCIe slot i have the card in, is the only GPU dedicated PCI slot, but i might be wrong there (don't have that much experience).

Comment: It's properbly your graphics card that doesn't work. If you have another computer you can try to plug it into that (make sure it fits). You can check if there is any physical damage to the GPU. Make sure the fans are spinning, that you have plugged you connectors correctly in etc. You can also try to plug in another display connector (if you have DVI connected then try and use HDMI instead). It could also be the cable to your monitor.